Book about a teen boy who is obsessed with finding aliens, then finds out he's an alien and grows tentacles on his back
I read this around 2019 and it was most likely written in the 2010s for ages 9-14.
It was about a teenage boy who's super obsessed with finding aliens and proving they're real in his school's newspaper. One day, he loses all of his fingerprints and grows tentacles on his back at like this party at his crush's house(?) and he finds out he's half-alien.
I thought it was called Tentacles but I looked it up and Tentacles (2009) by Roland Smith is not it.
